# Apache Camel SFTP download is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, sftp

I am trying to download file from SFTP server location but log looks good finally nothing is downloaded from the server to local.No errors also coming.Please give your inputs thanks in advance.

**SFTP files available:**

```
[root@rsysftp test1]# ls /tmp/files/test1
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt  test4.txt
```

**Router:**

```
@Component
public class SampleCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(10);

        from("sftp://ftpuser1@some.ip.value.here/tmp/files/test1?password=pass")
                .to("file:C:/out")
                .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
    }

}
```

**Log:**

```
o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: sftp://ftpuser1@some.ip.value.here/tmp/files/test1/test1.txt?password=xxxxxx
o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started.
o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: SampleCamel) started in 30.871 seconds
s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
c.camel.examples.SampleCamelApplication  : Started SampleCamelApplication in 37.837 seconds (JVM running for 38.891)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Windows version? Did you try with some other file e.g. `C:/Test/out`?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Windows7 and how changing location could behave differently?

Comment: Yes. There might be issues with permissions sometimes. Did you check if there is any file at the path that you used i.e. `C:\out`? And, try with some other path and test again.

Comment: I tried to include   File file = new File("C:/Users/a591470/Downloads/test/test10.txt");
  file.createNewFile(); code also part of the router but this creates file so permission issue is not there.

Comment: Good. Can you try to print the downloaded contents on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File is downloading from the Server successfully but location is different so without files it is not able to download.

```
Location from download :ftpuser1@some.ip.value.here/tmp/uta/test1
Location from downloaded:ftpuser1@some.ip.value.here/home/user/tmp/uta/test1
```

It is creating the uploading directory inside the user home directory that is the reason it is not available in expected directory.